# CKAN Error on docker-compose up (Command 'db' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info))

Tags: docker, ckan

I do all the steps written in the docs, after `docker-compose up -d --build`  ckan container go to Exited status

`docker logs ckan` show

```
db:5432 - accepting connections
No handlers could be found for logger "ckan.lib.maintain"
Command 'db' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
```

`docker-compose restart ckan` - doesn't change anything

What can be wrong?

```
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                    NAMES
ad9613d790f9        docker_ckan                 "/ckan-entrypoint.sh…"   2 hours ago         Exited (2) 2 hours ago                            ckan
8a0bfb6af229        redis:latest                "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours               0.0.0.0:6379->6379/tcp   redis
51b879900262        docker_solr                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours               0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp   solr
500f1b1438bf        clementmouchet/datapusher   "python datapusher/m…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours               0.0.0.0:8800->8800/tcp   datapusher
b0197d6cec5a        docker_db                   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 hours ago         Up 2 hours (healthy)     0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp   db
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't do it all of a sudden ㅠㅠ

You can try it by changing the tag.

```
$git checkout tags/ckan-2.8.0
or
$git checkout tags/ckan-2.8.5
or
$git checkout tags/ckan-2.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

First download the last Ckan git repository.

Create a *new branch* from master and run:

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

Work for me.

Read this:

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/issues/5572

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/5381